# Java Web Service - Android App HTTPS/SSL

Tags: java, android, web-services, ssl

I have a question regarding my Java Web Service and my Android App. I want to use https now and want to make sure, that I am on the right way:

Do I have to install a certificate on my server and just update the web.xml within my webservice? (Switch to confidential)
In my android app I have to use the right Libs to access the Web service.

Is it so simple?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like OkHttp to communicate with your service.

I'm guessing you are using a self-signed certificate so to use SSL you need to configure an SSLContext and add your server certificate to the trust store.

Then you initialize OkHttp using the SSLContext.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. So I will install the SSL certificate on my server and use SSLContext within my Webservice and initialize a connection with OkHttp from my Android app?

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for the back-end. This will give you the mighty **s** in **https** and on android just rename your URLs from HTTP -> HTTPS. I've used this method with Android Volley to create a RESTful service and it just worked by correcting the protocol inside the URL.

Comment: Hi, that is a very simple and quick solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you believe that is the correct answer mark it as correct please and upvote ;)

Comment: Hi, yea just one quick question again: Do I have to update the web.xml file? THanks

Comment: I usually do not work with back-end so I do not know exactly